# Matrix subtraction program c++

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm very new to programming, and I have a project where I need to take in two 6-by-2 matrices from a separate data file containing the life expectancy of black and white males/females in each decade from 1950 to 2000, then subtract the matrices to form a third 6-by-2 matrix containing the difference between the life expectancy of males and females of the same race in each decade.  We didn't cover multidimensional arrays in class, and I'm a bit confused by this.  I get a lot of errors saying undeclared identifier. I also know there has to be a better way to get the arrays from the data file, but I'm not sure how. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void getMatrixFemaleW();
void getMatrixFemaleB();
void getMatrixMaleW();
void getMatrixMaleB();
void matrix_diff();

int main()
{
   float matrixFemale[6][2];
   getMatrixFemaleW;
   getMatrixFemaleB;
   float matrixMale [6][2];
   getMatrixMaleW;
   getMatrixMaleB;
   float matrixDifference[6][2];
   matrix_diff;
   for (int x=0; x<6; x++)
   {
      for (int y=0; y<2; y++)
      {
         cout << matrixFemale[x][y] << " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
}

void getMatrixFemaleW()
{
   ifstream inputFile;
   inputFile.open("MatrixFemaleW.txt");
   int count = 0;
   while (count < 6 && inputFile >> matrixFemale[count][0])
      count++;

}

void getMatrixFemaleB()
{
   ifstream inputFile;
   inputFile.open("MatrixFemaleB.txt");
   int count = 0;
   while (count < 6 && inputFile >> matrixFemale[count][1])
      count++;

}

void getMatrixMaleW()
{
   ifstream inputFile;
   inputFile.open("MatrixMaleW.txt");
   int count = 0;
   while (count < 6 && inputFile >> matrixMale[count][0])
      count++;


void getMatrixMaleB()
{
   ifstream inputFile;
   inputFile.open("MatrixMaleB.txt");
   int count = 0;
   while (count < 6 && inputFile >> matrixMale[count][1])
      count++;

}
void matrix_diff()
{
   for (i=0; i<6; i++)
   {
      matrixDifference[i][0] = matrixFemale [i][0] - matrixMale[i][0];  
   }
   for (i=0 i<6; i++)
   {
      matrixDifference [i][1] = matrixFemale [i][1] - matrixMale [i][1];
   }

}
```

Comment: Number one rule of debugging programming errors:  *The error text matters*.  What is the exact error, and what line is it referring to?  For "undeclared identifier", if you look on that line, you will likely find a variable that you have not previously declared.

Comment: Looks like you are biting too much. Start small, get it work, and then add more code.

Comment: When all else fails, log into Stack Overflow and make the humans compile your code for you? ....  If you want help with specific errors, post the error message, and the relevant code.  Don't post all the code and the story of why you wrote it.

Comment: Probably your errors are related to trying to access **local** variables of on function inside another function.  *Local* variables have a reason for being called *local*.

Comment: How about `for (int i=0; i<6; i++)`. Notice the `int`.  But you have a bigger issue that you expect these functions to know about variables inside `main`, and you will need to pass them in.

Comment: Also, statements like `getMatrixMaleW;` are useless.  If want to call a function named `getMatrixMaleW`, you have to use parentheses (like `getMatrixMaleW();`).

Comment: Your problems have little to do with the multiple dimensions. It looks like you skipped over the parts of your course that covered variables, scope, and functions. Go back a bit and review.

Answer (score 0):

first these lines should be

```
getMatrixFemaleW();
getMatrixFemaleB();
getMatrixMaleW();
getMatrixMaleB();
matrix_diff();
```

because they are fuctions not variables you need to call them not declear them
then if you wanna reach a variable from outher function it should be global variable or a pointer that means

```
float matrixFemale[6][2];
float matrixMale [6][2];
float matrixDifference[6][2];
```

make these variables global variable or pointers

Comment: That's what the problem was, I got it to work. Thanks very much.